# Javascript used for random button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in JavaScript means and programming, and I encountered a problem for a personal project. I made an anime fight website getting some information from MySQL Database each anime has ten videos and photos, through a random button it randomly takes one link for a video and photo. The problem is that it only work only one time if I random again nothing happens. I know that in order to make that work I have to rewrite the code again after the success of the first random for getting a second random but this will create an infinite loop. Can somebody help me solve this issue.

This is the code used:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.imgResponsive').click(function(){
    $('#hiddenPage').hide();
    $('#hiddenPage').html('<center><img src="img/loading.gif"></center>');
    $('#hiddenPage').show();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/handler.php',
      data: {
        anime: $(this).prev().val()
      },
      success: function(response){
        $('#hiddenPage').html(response);
        $('#random').click(function(){
        $('#hiddenPage').hide();
        $('#hiddenPage').html('<center><img src="img/loading.gif"></center>');
        $('#hiddenPage').show();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'php/handler.php',
          data: {
            anime: $(this).prev().val()
          },
          success: function(response){
            $('#hiddenPage').html(response);   
          }
        });
      })
      }
    });
  })
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Why do u want to tie the random functionality in javascript?. Let the button be independant and rely an Id back to your controller(php or whatever backend ), based on which u pick the random ones and sent back. the id is sent back so that you can tie the selected values for that user along multiple requests. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: We need some HTML to see the structure of the DOM, otherwise we have no idea what `$('#hiddenPage').html(response);` could be messing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that *$.ajax* request overwrites initial *.imgResponsive* element, am I right? Along with overwritten *.imgResponsive* you permanently lose click event attached to this element.

In that case you need to attach event to element container, eg.

```
$(document).on('click', '.imgResponsive', function() {....
   ...
}
```

instead of

```
$('.imgResponsive').click(function(){ ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written, you're handling only a single AJAX response (aside from the first one) with no way to handle more AJAX requests triggered by clicking the #random button. You need to write functions for handling button clicks and the AJAX responses instead of using anonymous functions; that way it's modular enough that you can listen for and handle more button clicks in the future.

Something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.imgResponsive').click(function(){
    $('#hiddenPage').hide();
    $('#hiddenPage').html('<center><img src="img/loading.gif"></center>');
    $('#hiddenPage').show();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/handler.php',
      data: {
        anime: $(this).prev().val()
      },
      success: handleResponse
    });
    $('#random').click(handleButtonClick);
  });

  function handleButtonClick(e){
        $('#hiddenPage').hide();
        $('#hiddenPage').html('<center><img src="img/loading.gif"></center>');
        $('#hiddenPage').show();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'php/handler.php',
          data: {
            anime: $(this).prev().val()
          },
          success: handleResponse
        });
  }

  function handleResponse(response){
        $('#hiddenPage').html(response);
  }
}); 
</script>
```

Edit: Another thing that might be happening is that your `#random` element is being overwritten every time you do `$('#hiddenPage').html(response);`. In that case you would need to attach a new event handler to the new `#random` element every time you handle an AJAX response:

```
  function handleResponse(response){
        $('#hiddenPage').html(response);
        $('#random').click(handleButtonClick);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register EventListener in order to proceed.
Try this:

```
 <script>
 var showImage = function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#hiddenPage').hide();
            $('#hiddenPage').html('<center><img src="img/loading.gif"></center>');
            $('#hiddenPage').show();
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'php/handler.php',
              data: {
                anime: $(this).prev().val()
              },
              success: function(response){
                $('#hiddenPage').html(response);
              }
           });
        };
$(document).ready(function () {
          $('document').on('click', '.imgResponsive', showImage);
          $('document').on('click','#random', showImage);
});


</script>
```